# ansible-playbook not able to use .bashrc env variables

Tags: ansible, bashrc

I'm using ansible-playbook to deploy my django application to Ubuntu servers. I'm storing my django environment variables in .bashrc file of the user ubuntu in the server. But my ansible-playbook is not using the env variables in .bashrc even when i'm running as ubuntu user. Is there any way for me to access these env variables using ansible-playbook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22256884/2947502

Comment: @techraf i'm having issues with accessing the values that i add in .bashrc when i run some commands using ansible. I can add the values but ansile-playbook is not using these values when i run some commands.

Comment: Of course you have, because bash does not read `.bashrc` in non-interactive mode.

Comment: @techraf then how can i run django management commands in ansible using the variables in .bashrc

Answer (score 2):

I use this one:

```
  - shell: . ~/.bashrc  && echo $LS_COLORS
    args: 
      executable: /bin/bash
    register: result

  - set_fact:
      ls_colors: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works so your code looks cleaner

```
- name: Use ruby 2.6.6
  shell: |
    source ~/.bashrc
    rvm use 2.6.6
    gem install fastlane

- name: Use ruby 2.6.6
  shell: |
    source ~/.bash_profile
    rvm use 2.6.6
    gem install fastlane
```